Correctly handling weekly pattern in python TimeSeries modeling
Currently, I'm working on modeling TimeSeries data using python and darts library. Let's consider TiDE model as an example (but I'm not attached to it in any way). The important thing is that my data has a specific weekly pattern. The value changes from Monday to Friday and remains constant during the weekend. I load my data from the file, but you can use any type of data that satisfies this weekly pattern. An easier example would be to take stock prices, as most of the stock exchanges work in such a weekly pattern:
series = TimeSeries.from_dataframe(df_single, "Date", varName)
days = pd.date_range(start=df_single["Date"][0], periods=len(df_single), freq='D')

# Create a binary covariate: 0 for weekdays, 1 for weekends
weekend_covariate = [1 if day.weekday() in [5, 6] else 0 for day in days]
extended_covariate = TimeSeries.from_times_and_values(days, weekend_covariate)

# Split data into training and validation sets
train_series = series[:-14]  # Train on all but the last 14 days
val_series = series[-14:]  # Validate on the last 14 days
covariates_train = extended_covariate[:-14]
covariates_val = extended_covariate  # Covariates must cover both past and future

# Define TFTModel (supports future covariates)
model = TiDEModel(
    input_chunk_length=92,  # Number of past days to look at
    output_chunk_length=14,  # Forecast horizon
    n_epochs=50,
    random_state=42
)

# Fit the model on training data and future covariates
model.fit(series=train_series, future_covariates=covariates_train)

# Make predictions
prediction = model.predict(n=14, future_covariates=covariates_val)

I was expecting that the binary covariate giving 1 for weekend and 0 for working day would help the model to recognize the pattern. But it seems that it doesn't matter, it still fails to recognize the correlation, and it tends to change the modeled data value on weekends. See the plot below that compares real data with model forecast, I marked weekends in the covering range:

So my question is: how to correctly add constraints to the model to recognize weekends correctly?
